# There was no endpoint listening at XXX that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

Tags: c#

how can I solve this?

There was no endpoint listening at https://190.0.195.24:9001/paymentgw/services/paymentgw?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cadenaserver" connectionString="Data Source=SQL7001.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A2CE26_PaymentDB;User Id=DB_A2CE26_PaymentDB_admin;Password=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="cadenaserverb" connectionString="Data Source=SQL7001.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A2CE26_PaymentDB;User Id=DB_A2CE26_PaymentDBBackUp_admin;Password=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="cadenalocal" connectionString="Data Source=DAVID-HP\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=DB_A2CE26_PaymentDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://190.0.195.24:9001/paymentgw/services/paymentgw"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PaymentGW_SOAPBinding"
        contract="VisaNetWSTest.PaymentGW" name="PaymentGWServicesPort" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="PaymentGW_SOAPBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="PaymentGW_SOAPBinding1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Comment: When I go to that URL I get an SSL certificate error. If using HTTPS use the name provided in the SSL cert or test with HTTP Only

Comment: I ignore the certificate when I connect, in my localhost Works fine, is on the online server that I have the problem